Oracle connection fails in newer builds, but works in QGIS version 3.22.16-Białowieża
I've used QGIS version 3.22.16-Białowieża for quite a long time now without problems with Oracle (v19) connections.
We are now upgrading our application, so I installed first the LTS (3.34.13) version, but I could not connect to the Oracle database. Then installed QGIS version 3.40.1-Bratislava, but the problem still exists.
I've tried to test a connection with (besides user name and password):

only a database/TNS name
database service name, localhost, port 1521
and all other combinations

But I cannot get it to work...
Do I oversee something? Or am I doing something wrong?
QGIS version
3.40.1-Bratislava
QGIS code revision
989853a7
 
Libraries
Qt version
5.15.13
Python version
3.12.7
GDAL/OGR version
3.9.3
PROJ version
9.5.0
EPSG Registry database version
v11.016 (2024-08-31)
GEOS version
3.13.0-CAPI-1.19.0
SQLite version
3.46.1
PDAL version
2.8.1
PostgreSQL client version
16.2
SpatiaLite version
5.1.0
QWT version
6.3.0
QScintilla2 version
2.14.1
OS version
Windows 11 Version 2009
 
Active Python plugins
pdok_locatieserver_locator_filter
0.2.1
db_manager
0.1.20
grassprovider
2.12.99
MetaSearch
0.3.6
processing
2.12.99

QGIS version
3.22.16-Białowieża
QGIS code revision
6f08e4d7
Qt version
5.15.3
Python version
3.9.5
GDAL/OGR version
3.6.2
PROJ version
9.1.1
EPSG Registry database version
v10.076 (2022-08-31)
GEOS version
3.11.1-CAPI-1.17.1
SQLite version
3.39.4
PDAL version
2.4.3
PostgreSQL client version
14.3
SpatiaLite version
5.0.1
QWT version
6.1.6
QScintilla2 version
2.13.1
OS version
Windows 10 Version 2009




Active Python plugins
pdok_locatieserver_locator_filter
0.2.1
db_manager
0.1.20
grassprovider
2.12.99
MetaSearch
0.3.5
processing
2.12.99
sagaprovider
2.12.99


Does your installation have the Oracle (OCI) driver? Check from Settings -  Options - Data Sources - GDAL - Vector Drivers.

Yep, it has. I wouldn't even know how to install QGis without them... ;) But thanks for the suggestion!

Turns out I had to change sqlnet.ora.
From:
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

to
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)

